# Can a pet dog be a carrier of chickenpox?

Tags: chickenpox, carrier-genetic, animal-dander, vector, zoonotic-viruses

Can a pet dog be a carrier of chickenpox after contact with a person who has currently suffered chickenpox?

Answer (score 3):

From [Chickenpox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chickenpox):

> ## Other animals
>
> Humans are the only known animal that the disease affects naturally. However, chickenpox has been caused in other primates, including chimpanzees and gorillas.

The *varicella zoster* virus cannot infect dogs.

Answer (score 0):

No,dogs cannot get chicken pox. you must first know what an anthroponotic disease is. It means that it is a contagious disease wherein a pathogen found in humans is transmitted to animal species. Once a pathogen transfers to animals, at times it may result to the same disease found in humans with a few significant differences in presentation. Chicken pox not being an anthroponotic disease means that it is not transmissible to your pets.

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). We require that all answers are backed up with reliable references, since they are the only way for the community to assess the merit of an answer regardless of the reader's background. You can always [edit] your answer to add some. For more information on site policies, please take our [tour] or visit the [help] and [meta]. Thanks!